how to fetch datetime type correctly from duckdb using rust?
I'm a python guy trying to do a few things in Rust.
I'm using duckdb = { version = "0.10.2", features = ["bundled"] }
I have this bit of code:
    for row in rows {
        let (laterality, scan_date_days, modality, file_path) = row.unwrap();
        let scan_date = NaiveDate::from_num_days_from_ce(scan_date_days);
        let file_name = Path::new(&file_path)
            .file_name()
            .unwrap()
            .to_string_lossy()
            .to_string();
        let output_file_name = format!("{}_{}", modality, file_name);
        let formatted_date = scan_date.format("%d-%b-%Y").to_string().to_uppercase();
        let patient_folder = Path::new(output_directory)
            .join(format!("{}_{}_{}", patient_id, laterality, formatted_date));

First, I'm failing to move from from_num_days_from_ce to from_num_days_from_ce_opt.
In python, scan_date_days is datetime object (e.g. datetime.date(2017, 12, 18)). And I get the  right formatted_date: 18-DEC-2017.
However, the rust code above is giving 17-DEC-0048.
What am I missing, please?

Looks like you have the number of days since unix epoch. Can you try: NaiveDate::from_ymd_opt(1970, 1, 1).unwrap().checked_add_days(Days::new(scan_date_days)).unwrap()?

Your suggestion really did the trick! I also had to change scan_date type from i32 to u64 and now it seems to be working fine. Many thanks.
If you want to write an answer, please go ahead and I will mark it the correct one.

From the values you're showing, it looks like DuckDB is returning the number of days since Unix Epoch (Jan 1 1970). To convert that to a NaiveDateTime, you can do this:
let epoch = NaiveDate::from_ymd_opt(1970, 1, 1).unwrap();

for row in rows {
    ...

    let naive_date = epoch.checked_add_days(Days::new(scan_date_days)).unwrap();
    ...
}


